# Spray.io not respond css file

Tags: spray

I have a spray application.

```
 //src/main/resources/twirl/app/index.scala.html 
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

   <head lang="en">
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/file.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
     ...
   </body>
 </html>
```

In `src/main/resources/css/file.css` my css file with styles.

My Service:

```
 //src/main/scala/app/service.scala
 trait MyRoute extends HttpService {
   val route = pathPrefix("") {
     get {
       respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) {
         complete {
           app.html.index.render
         }
       }
     }
  } ~
  pathPrefix("css") {
    get {
      getFromResourceDirectory("css")
    }
  }

  class MyActor extends Actor with MyRoute {
    def actorRefFactory = context
    def receive = runRoute(route)
  }

  //main app
  object Main extends App {
   implicit val system = ActorSystem("app")
   val service = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], "my-service")

   IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(service, "localhost", port = 8080)
  }
```

When i run this application, i then i got in chrome console: `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/css/file.css".`

And instead of `file.css` content, i got a `index.scala.html` content. How to return `css` static file with spray.io?

Comment: `pathPrefix("")` matches more than you think. Therefore, your first route part will match most requests. Use `pathSingleSlash`, instead, for the empty path. Also `respondWithMediaType` is almost never necessary. `getFromResourceDirectory` already includes `get` so you can leave `get` away when using `getFromResourceDirectory`.

Comment: ou, thanks. I do not know about this. Thanks